# Parsing multiple checkbox values as a List

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm making a web application using MVC3 with C#

I would like to get the checkboxes in my view defined as:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="group1[]" value="1" /> 
<input type="checkbox" name="group1[]" value="2" />
<input type="checkbox" name="group1[]" value="3" />
```

to be available as an List of values in the formCollection of a post method.

When I put a breakpoint it looks like the "group1" entry in the formCollection is indeed a list but I don't know how to get it using the formCollection.Get method.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="group1[0]" value="1" /> 
<input type="checkbox" name="group1[1]" value="2" />
<input type="checkbox" name="group1[2]" value="3" />
```

Try using this